# Query date on datetime stored within jsonfield in Postgres through Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, jsonb

I have a Postgres table with a `jsonb` column containing UTC timestamp data in ISO format like the following:

```
{
    "time": "2021-04-13T20:14:56Z"
}
```

The Django model for this table looks like:

```
class DateModel(models.Model):
    values = models.JSONField(default=dict)
```

I need to query the table for all records with a timestamp on a certain date (ignoring time)

I'm looking for a solution similar to the following:

```
DateModel.objects.filter(values__time__date='2021-04-13')
```

The other solution I have found is to query for records with date greater than the previous day and less than the next one. This works but I am looking for a way to do it with a single query so the code would be more concise.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of annotations you need to perform on the queryset to extract the time field and convert it to a datetime.

First you need to extract the time string by using `django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.KeyTextTransform`

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTextTransform

query = DateModel.objects.annotate(time_str=KeyTextTransform('time', 'values'))
```

Then you need to convert that string to a datetime using `Cast`

```
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
from django.db.models import DateTimeField

query = query.annotate(time=Cast('time_str', output_field=DateTimeField()))
```

Then you can filter by that annotation

```
query = query.filter(time__date='2021-04-13')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I played with it a little bit, and it turns out that we can do it without using KeyTextTransform. We would just need to do to Casts:
`query.annotate(
    time_str=time=Cast('values__time', output_field=TextField()))
).annotate(time=Cast('time_str', output_field=DateTimeField()))`

Comment: To add to this: If you don't want the intermediate text value in the results, you can use `.alias()` to create it and then use it in `.annotate()`. I'm currently doing this in a custom manager using UUID aliases to allow arbitrary numbers of annotated dates/times/datetimes added to queries (we're _way_ too dependent on JSON fields, unfortunately).